# How to convert a time series quarterly data(4 quarters ) into a single column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, forecasting

I have a time series raw data.

[image: time series excel screenshot]

Can I combine all 4 Quarter column into single column to get good forecast or should i keep it.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: quarters in to a single column ? you mean to add all quarters data to single column as say total=(Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4) ?

Comment: Try it both ways and see what each forecast looks like.

Comment: Welcome new contributor, btw. You can combine the columns easily using something like `df['YR'] = df['Q1'] + df['Q2'] +df['Q3'] + df['Q4']` that generates a new column, 'YR' and retains the quarterly data. Then you can see what it does for your forecast methodology and get rid of the quarterly columns if you choose not to keep them. @DeeptiGupta

Answer (score 0):

```
d={'Year':[96, 97], 'Q1':[2.3,3.4], 'Q2':[4.5,7.8]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Year'])
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: You are right. Noted. Was on the fly then. Should have gone back to explain. Good feeback.

Answer (score 0):

no need to convert Quarter data into single column. You can forecast on Quarter also.
If you combine Quarter then you will get whole Year in single column.

Comment: Do I need to convert columns into rows to make two columns one for date and other for quarters to build a model in Pandas? In R we can do with quarters but in Pandas?

Comment: Yes, you have convert column into rows, your column should look like this Year, Quarter Value or combine year and quarter column like 1996-Q1, 1996-Q2,etc